# In the view if I select id I want to retrieve more than one columns from table to text directly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Here I want to dynamically select the `electionName` once the user select the `electionId`.

Model :

```
public virtual int ElectionId { get; set; }
public virtual string ElectionName { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(votingModel chk)
{
    var id = chk.ElectionId;
    if (db.votingModels.Find(id) == id)
    {
        // i want to do like this directly to the textbox is possible
        //string name = "select electionName from tabel where electionId =id";
    }
```

And as soon as the user entered the text of id directly the election name should appear in the view.

View:

```
 @model election.Models.votingModel

 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "index";
  }
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @*<p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>*@
    @Html.Label("election ID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ElectionId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ElectionId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    @Html.Label("election name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ElectionName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ElectionName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        @Html.Label("election Reason", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Reason, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.reason, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
    etc .......
```

kindly if somebody knows let me know

Comment: Seems that you need JS to perform AJAX call (`$.ajax`) and wrap `ElectionName` control in a partial view which viewmodel value assigned from controller action method with `return PartialView`.

Comment: @Testsuya Yamamoto 
can you explain in details what to write and implement ?

Comment: A little note: Why `ElectionId` uses `TextBoxFor` there? Use `DropDownListFor` if you want to select election IDs from a list, which then triggers AJAX call to a controller method which receives an election ID as argument and set corresponding election name in partial view.

Comment: in fact i dont want the user to see all the ElectionId and view them , only the one who has the id can write description and select his candidate,

Comment: Is that likely to be `autocomplete` which inserts the election name automatically when an election ID is entered? If that's what you want, you can use `change` event in JS and put AJAX call to find election name with certain kind of query and set it in partial view.

Comment: yup exactly , so how to make the syntax and coding for that , your help will be appreciated